# When opening n pipes to child processes executing xargs from Perl, n-1 processes receive an empty line

Tags: perl, pipe, xargs

...on the other side if I write something to the pipes before opening the next one, this doesn't happen.

The following code should make it clearer:

```
sub test_concurrent_pipes
{
    my $write_at_once = $_[0];
    my $pipe_handle;
    my @pipe_handle_list;
    my $i;
    foreach $i ( 1..3 )
    {
        open ( $pipe_handle, "| xargs echo" ) or die ( "Cannot open pipe.\n" );
        if ( $write_at_once == 1 )
        {
          print $pipe_handle "Hello\n";
        }
        push( @pipe_handle_list, $pipe_handle );
    }
    foreach $pipe_handle ( @pipe_handle_list )
    {
        print $pipe_handle "world\n";
    }
    foreach $pipe_handle ( @pipe_handle_list )
    {
        close ( $pipe_handle );
    }
}

print "Test 0: open all pipes before writing\n";
test_concurrent_pipes(0);

print "Test 1: write Hello before opening next pipe\n";
test_concurrent_pipes(1);
```

Running the test I get

```
./test_pipe_2_xargs.pl 
Test 0: open all pipes before writing


world world world
Test 1: write Hello before opening next pipe
Hello
Hello
Hello world world world
```

As you can see in Test 0, opening the 3 pipes in a row without any output in between generates 2 empty lines.
Strangely enough, if I substitute `xargs echo` with `cat -` there are not empty lines produced.
The xargs behavior seems also to contradict its man page, which states `Blank lines on the standard input are ignored.`

How can I avoid those empty lines?

This happens with Perl 5.14.2 on cygwin/XP and with Perl 5.8.8 on HP-UX 11.00.

I write what I'm really trying to do at the end, since it's irrelevant here:

efficiently cleanup all derived objects visible from all Clearcase views through a Perl script which forks one process per view to remove the files (xargs rm) before removing them from the VOBs (rmdo).

Comment: Well done on supplying a complete example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Making "creation loop" use local variable ( `my $pipe_handle` ) fixes the problem.

```
foreach $i ( 1..3 )
{
    open ( my $pipe_handle, "| xargs echo" ) or die ( "Cannot open pipe.\n" );
    ...
}
```

Comment: I will vote you up if you explain why in 3 sentences or less :-)

Comment: Combining your answer with @fjardon's note regarding the `open()` documentation my quick "grok" is that scoping with`my` is equivalent to having `$pipe_handle`  be undefined at the moment `open` is called.

Comment: Anything scoped with `my` is local to the current code block. In the Q it's outside the `foreach` so it's being reused - and thus the next 'open' is clobbering it.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently `open` overwrote the FILEHANDLE pointed to by `$pipe_handle`, making all the references in `@pipe_hanlde_list` points to the latest open pipe.

The documentation states that `$pipe_handle`should be undefined when calling `open()`...

Answer (score 1):

Not to contradict the answer above, but I think you're going about this a strange way. Why do you need to concurrently pipe anything?

I don't think you're actually getting any parallelism - you're just asynchronously feeding a pipe. Particularly with things like `rm` though, which you allude to - your limiting factor will almost never be the processes and CPU, and rather it'll be the disk IO.

In your example above - you're building file lists in xargs asynchronously, but it won't actually do anything with the command until the file descriptor is `close`ed. If you weren't looking to do filesystem IO, I'd be suggesting using threading or forking, but unlinking files doesn't parallelise particularly well.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Filip for giving the right answer and to fjardon and Sobrique for pinpointing the source of the problem.

After going through the `open` function documentation and some tests I understand that it can operate in two ways:
- either the handle is undefined, in which case it creates a new one
- or the handle argument is a scalar which becomes the name of the handle.
I find particularly interesting the example in the open documentation where C code files are opened recursively when encountering an `#include` directive and are assigned to numbered file handles (`fh<nn>` in `process` function).

So in my case each `open` clubbers (and closes) the previously opened handle (except for the first call). Therefore the list contains three handles to the same pipe.
Note: since I was using `use strict` I would have expected Perl to complain about using symbolic references (`strict refs` generates runtime errors when using symbolic references).

@Sobrique: as a side note, after correcting the real script and doing some benchmarking, it turns out that executing the commands in parallel does make a difference.
To benchmark I piped 700 file names to an `xargs cleartool ls` running in 17 views and got it done 37% faster (real time) when executed in parallel.
This is most likely related to having one process running per view, Clearcase caching and Clearcase internals unrelated to IO.
But I don’t want to start a discussion about performance here, the main problem has been understood and solved.
Thanks to all, I appreciated every input.